# Jackson custom complex deserializer into classes

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I need to use custom deserializer for my json string. The problem is that my class I want to serialize in is very complex and constructed from other classes. But all of the examples in the internet show only very basic way of deserializing jsons (i.e. only retrieving one value by name and getting it's value), but I have subclasses and want to use them so I don't need to write manually all of the mapping. Is there any way I can do this? Example to understand what I'm talking about, so let's say I have this structure:

```
public TestClass{
public Class1 first;
public Class2 second;
...
public Class10 ten;
}
```

And all of the classes contain the data, something like this:

```
public Class1{
public String name;
public int id;
...
}
```

Obviously I don't want to manually map all of that, but all of the examples in the internet show exactly that, is there any way to read the values into classes directly without needing doing manual mapping? For example most common example is to do something like this:

```
@Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        int id = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("id")).numberValue();
        String itemName = node.get("itemName").asText();
        int userId = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("createdBy")).numberValue();

        return new Item(id, itemName, new User(userId, null));
    }
```

So my question is can I do this more easily, i.e. reading values directly into these classes? (Except the one, that's why I need the custom deserilizing at the first place, but it's better to write only one manual mapping instead of 10).
Summurizing, I want to do something like this:

```
@Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ...
        Testclass test = new Testclass();
        Class1 class1 = json...parse(..., Class1.class);
        Class2 class2 = json...parse(..., Class2.class);
        ...
        test.setClass1(class1);
        test.setClass2(class2);
        ...
        Class10 manualClass = new Class10();
        manualClass.setField1(json.get("class10").get("field1").stringValue());
        ...
        test.setClass10(manualClass);
    }
```

Comment: please show the json structure to deal with

Comment: @MarcStroebel, I already showed example in the question, you don't need to know my exact structure to show me how to do it

Comment: generic solution is to use custom transformers ;-) to optimize you need to know details...

Comment: @MarcStroebel, I added more detailed example, if it will help somehow

Comment: Do you have special needs when it comes to include or exclude member fields? Do the member fields of the classes have the same name as the JSON properties? Do you have control over all classes involved (besides the Java own API like `String` etc. of course)?

Comment: Oh, and do your classes have regular beans-style getters and setters? e.g. `getField1` / `setField1` to be called for the JSON property `field1`.

Comment: you dont need to use json parser. serialize and deserialize is mostly automatic. can you put a reproducer to github ? and show what you are trying to reach ?

Comment: May this Is help for you: [Mapping Nested Values with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values)

Comment: And read this article [JSON to Java Object](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial#2-json-to-java-object). So annotate classes, properties, than use objectMapper.

Comment: why don't u use the ObjectMapper.readValue(most types are supported, Your.class) ?
it is exactly like what u need. in case u feel it is close to what u need just tell me to provide a detailed answer if u need

Comment: You start your question with "I need to use custom deserializer for my json string", but you are unwilling to provide a sample of that string, not even a minimal piece. It is actually quite difficult to understand what you want help with from your example classes and code... I think a simple piece of json would change that, and probably quickly render a few answers...

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing external names with internal variables. A 'public string name' internal variable cannot be automatically correlated with a "name" string. (Except maybe with java reflection, but I wouldn't risk it).
In any case, you will have to indicate the mapping between 'name' and the internal variable by a mapper. On some projects, I hold the internal variables of the classes as maps to have a direct correspondence through key names. You can then create an automatic mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74539561/231860) by Oleg is a good one for what you want to do.

There is a little known feature with Jackson called **[Mixins](https://medium.com/@shankar.ganesh.1234/jackson-mixin-a-simple-guide-to-a-powerful-feature-d984341dc9e2)**. They allow you to provide overrides, annotations and any other desired modifications just to specific places in your complex object graph. This means that you can customize specific aspects of the serialization without having to implement a whole new serializer.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Class1.class, Class1Mixin.class);

public Class1
{
   public String name;
   public int id;    
}

public abstract Class1Mixin
{
   // Override 'name' to serialize as 'fullName'. Leave the id the same.
   @JsonProperty("fullName")
   public String name;    
}
```

Think of if as being able to overlay annotations on top of little sections of the object graph without polluting your original classes. Super handy for keeping Models clean and using **[Mixins](https://medium.com/@shankar.ganesh.1234/jackson-mixin-a-simple-guide-to-a-powerful-feature-d984341dc9e2)** to specify how to make them Data Transfer Objects(DTO)/Messages.

Comment: Idk why the bounty went to you, but this is not an answer for anyone who wants to know the answer

Comment: @Arzybek because it is a bad practice don't spend declared bounty

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can just use

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "..." //some json from any source with complex structure related to TestClass structure 
TestClass result = objectMapper.readValue(json, TestClass.class)
```

Usually it is enough for many cases. Any custom deserilizer depends on what do you want to change in the default deserializer. Anyway we can help with customization if you clarify your case with json example